# fetch results from different tables using one ActionResult based on selected <select> value in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two model classes - Facility and Animals, and there is no relation between them. There are different animals assigned to different facilities, but there is no link between animals and facilities at database level. Every facility is a different table. So. Then I have a repository class for ADO.NET code. Here under is a call for first facility.

```
public List<Animals> GetAllAnimalsForFirstFacility() {
    List<Animals> animals = new List<Animals>();
    String query = String.Format("SELECT ANIMALCODE, ANIMALNAME, FACILITYCODE FROM ANIMALS INNER JOIN FACILITYONE ON FACILITYCODE = FACILITYCODE");
    newConnection.OpenConnection();
    SqlCommand command = new command(query, newConnection.SQLConnectionInstance);
    SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    Animals animalList = null;
    while (dataReader.Read()) {
        animalList = new Animals();
        animalList.AnimalCode = (dataReader["ANIMALCODE"]);
        animalList.AnimalName = (dataReader["ANIMALNAME"]);
        animalList.FacilityCode = (dataReader["FACILITYCODE"]);
        animals.Add(animalList);
    }
    return animals;
}
```

And here is a call for second facility

```
public List<Animals> GetAllAnimalsForSecondFacility() {
            List<Animals> animals = new List<Animals>();
            string query = String.Format("SELECT ANIMALCODE, ANIMALNAME, FACILITYCODE FROM ANIMALS INNER JOIN FACILITYTWO ON FACILITYCODE = FACILITYCODE");
            newConnection.OpenConnection();
            SqlCommand command = new command(query, newConnection.SQLConnectionInstance);
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Animals animalList = null;
            while (dataReader.Read()) {
                animalList = new Animals();

                    animalList.AnimalCode = (dataReader["ANIMALCODE"]);
animalList.AnimalName = (dataReader["ANIMALNAME"]);
animalList.FacilityCode = (dataReader["FACILITYCODE"]);

                animals.Add(animalList);
            }
            return animals;
        }
```

On view, there's a `<select>` (like here under) and a button and a table.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:170px" id="FacilitiesID" name="Facilities"></select>
```

I am feeding the `<select>` from the controller like this

```
[Route("")]
        public ActionResult FacilityList()
        {
            var facilities = Facilities.GetFacilities();

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(facilities.ToArray(), "FacilityCode", "FacilityDescription"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And this is the function that I am using to populate the table

```
[Route("GetAllAnimals")]
        public ActionResult GetAllAnimals()
        {
            AnimalsRepository animalsRepository = new AnimalsRepository();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(animalsRepository.GetAllAnimalsForFirstFacility());
        }
```

**

> Problem:

**

I want to select the facility via select and call this `public ActionResult GetAllAnimals()`, but want to modify it so that is does something like this.

```
[Route("GetAllAnimals")]
        public ActionResult GetAllAnimals()
        {
            AnimalsRepository animalsRepository = new AnimalsRepository();
            ModelState.Clear();
if(selectedvaluefromfacilityselect == "Facility one")
{
            return View(animalsRepository.GetAllAnimalsForFirstFacility());
}
else
{
return View(animalsRepository.GetAllAnimalsForSecondFacility());
}
        }
```

How do it do this?

Comment: **Every facility is a different table.** Why ? IMHO, You should fix your db schema design first before solving any UI concerns.

Comment: Its not a UI concern. Also, I agree with how it should be. That's why I took my time to explain that. But it can't be fixed for now.

Comment: Fixing your underlying db schema issues will save you a lot of time going further. Otherwise you have to keep making "work arounds"

Comment: Create 2 tables. One for Animals and one for Facility. Add a `FacilityId` column to your `Animal` table where you will store the Id fo the facility that animal belongs to.

Comment: Yeah but, like I said, it can't be done just yet.

Comment: Also, I do know how to make related tables.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could help me with it on _as is_ basis.

Comment: Look, I do know how to make primary keys and foreign keys and relate them. That's not the issue though.

Comment: How many rows are there in db . If not more than use simple linq query by fetching all data.

Comment: Still no response? :(

Comment: Maybe you can’t fix the table schema, but you can create a view that unions all the tables together.  Maybe you should query over that.